# NullReferenceException on Fresh Silverlight Project - Designer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, .net-4.5

I just created a new Silverlight project along side an existing web project. (Visual Studio 2010)

The designer window is now showing "An unhandled exception has occured".

**Note: The project has no additional code added, it has only the default code.**

*Part of the stacktrace is below.*

System.NullReferenceException

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     at

Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.d__8.MoveNext()

at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()

at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Install Silverlight Developer runtime to avoid the null refference exc the VisualStudio Designer